# How to set classname or title dynamically from database

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm having code like this

```
@foreach ($aRoom->room_amenity as $value)
   <?php //echo $value['name'];echo $value['class'];?>                      
   <li rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" value="" title="{{$value['name']}}"><i class="{{$value['class']}}"></i></li>
@endforeach
```

Here when I print the values using `<?php ?>` tag it show me the results but when I gave it in `title` and `class` it makes me an error.

How should I give the title and class in it.

And I don't know how to give title for my post.If you think,that my post is not having incorrect title,please change it.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
@foreach ($aRoom->room_amenity as $value)
   <li rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" value="" title="<?php echo $value['name'] ?>"><i class="<?php echo $value['class']; ?>"></i></li>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

What's the error? Is $value an object? There are some unclear things there. Have you tried doing this:

```
<li rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" value="" title="{{$value->name}}"><i class="{{$value->class}}"></i></li>
```